# How to efficiently create N sparse matrices in python without a for loop - and how to create an even bigger sparce matrix out of them?

Tags: scipy, storage, sparse-matrix

This question might be very naive - I tried finding an answer online but wasn't successful.

Essentially, I want to create a sparse block matrix, where the individual blocks are sparse and of size MxM. The whole matrix should be of size MNxMN.
The N blocks on the main diagonal are all similar to each other, but depend on their own "block index", i.e. A(j) where j <= N.

[The big sparse matrix, where A_j, B, C are sparse MxM matrices themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWBs6.png)

I'm using the scipy.sparse package (`diags`) to create the blocks B and C on the other diagonal but I have no idea how to efficiently (and with a good coding style) create the A_js.

My next issue is probably that I don't know how to create the big matrix out of these blocks - I looked at `scipy.sparse.bmat` but I don't know how this works for an arbitrary number of N.

So I guess my question is either:

1. How do I efficiently create and store the A_js? And how do I put them together in a big sparse matrix?
2. Alternatively, is there a way to directly create the big matrix?

I failed at the very start where I was unable to store N sparse diagonal matrices using a for loop, e.g. obviously the following does not work:

```
A = np.zeros(5)
for j in range(0,5):
    A[j] = j*scipy.sparse.diag(np.ones(3),shape(3,3))
```

EDIT:
This is not quite the answer to my original question but maybe it's helpful to someone: I used the fact that all my blocks are diagonal matrices and avoided working with the blocks completely. Instead, I used `scipy.sparse.spdiags()`. The diagonals - with entries dependent on indices - can then simply created with loops, e.g.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

M = 3
N = 5
C = np.arange(0,M)
d0 = np.zeros(M*N)
d1 = np.zeros(M*N)
dm1 = np.zeros(M*N)

dmM = np.ones(M*N)
dM = np.ones(M*N)

def somefunction(j):
    return np.sin(j)* j**2

for j in range(0,N):
    d0[j*M:(j+1)*M] = somefunction(j) * C
    dm1[j*M:(j+1)*M] = j*C
    d1[j*M:(j+1)*M] = j* C

data = np.zeros([5,M*N])
data[0,:] = dmM
data[1,:] = dm1
data[2,:] = d0
data[3,:] = d1
data[4,:] = dM

Matrix = scipy.sparse.spdiags(data,[-M,-1,0,1,M], M*N, M*N)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [scipy.sparse.bmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bmat.html).

Comment: The problem with the code sample is that `A`  holds floats not sparse array objects.  What input does `bmat` take?

Comment: @hpaulj : Thanks for your reply! I plan to use `bmat` -with matrices as inputs- to build the whole matrix at the end. But first I have to create the individual blocks, `A_j` matrices, which are N diagonal sparse matrices - I don't see how `bmat` can help me with that or am I missing something? 

In the meantime, I tried:
`for j in range(N):
    locals()["A"+str(j)] = scipy.sparse.diags([f(j),g(j),h(j)],[-1,0,1], ...)`

it somewhat does the job but I don't think this is an optimal solution. Also, I still need to put all of them together in the full matrix, I don't know if it will work.

Comment: The `bmat` examples show a list of lists input, which is converted internally to object dtype array.  (`bmat` code is python readable).  While there are some csr/csc shortcuts, the general procedure is to iterate through all MxN blocks, convert them to `coo` (if needed), and join their `data,row,col`  together to create the inputs to a new `coo_matrix`.

Comment: There is also a `sparse.block_diag` which takes a simple list of blocks, and does the same sort of joint `coo` construction.  It too is python readable code, and somewhat simpler.  But with your general `C Ai B` layout that may not help.  Another possibility is the `sparse.bsr_matrix` format.  I'm most familiar with the base formats, `coo`, `csr`, and have only played with these compound ones.  Creating a large sparse matrix is not a trivial task.

Comment: I think you need to write a small working example, without worrying about efficiency.  It's easier to suggest and test improvements to working code than to deduce all the required details from a word description.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of making a sparse matrix, roughly as you describe:

```
In [275]: B, C = sparse.coo_matrix(np.eye(3)), sparse.coo_matrix(np.eye(3))*2

In [276]: A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

In [277]: alist = [[A*1,B,None,None],[C,A*2,B,None],[None,C,A*3,B],[None,None,C,A*4]]

In [278]: M = sparse.bmat(alist)

In [279]: M
Out[279]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 50 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [280]: M.A
Out[280]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  4.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  6.,  8., 10.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2., 12., 14., 16.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  6.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  9., 12., 15.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2., 18., 21., 24.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  8.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0., 12., 16., 20.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2., 24., 28., 32.]])
```

Creating the `alist` could be done in a loop, but I wasn't going to worry about handling the corner conditions.  Writing it out in full was easiest.

Another way to make `alist` like, is to fill in an object dtype array:

```
In [292]: Arr = np.empty((4,4),object); Arr
Out[292]: 
array([[None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
In [293]: Arr[np.arange(1,4),np.arange(0,3)] = B # oops switch B and C
In [294]: Arr[np.arange(0,3),np.arange(1,4)] = C
In [295]: Arr[np.arange(4),np.arange(4)]=list(A*np.arange(1,5)[:,None,None])
In [296]: M1 = sparse.bmat(Arr)
```

But we could make the equivalent dense array with:

```
In [299]: AA = np.zeros((4,4,3,3))    
In [301]: AA[np.arange(1,4),np.arange(0,3)] = B.A    
In [302]: AA[np.arange(0,3),np.arange(1,4)] = C.A    
In [303]: AA[np.arange(4),np.arange(4)]=list(A*np.arange(1,5)[:,None,None])
```

And then re arrange elements with:

```
In [306]: AA.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(12,12)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the end I figured out a different way to create my sparse matrix, without the `bmat`. It's not quite what I asked here - I used the fact that I only have diagonals to build it and avoided working with the blocks in the end.